# How to get the input path in webpack output

Tags: javascript, webpack

I've got multiple javascript files for my website. Actually, for each page I got a slightly different one. I want webpack to output these files in the same directory structure as I input them, but with a prefix. This means that `./js/webshop/overview.js` becomes `./dist/js/webshop/overview.js`

How do I do this?

This is my current config code:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    index: './js/index.js',
    webshop_overview: './js/webshop/overview.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js', // Should be [file][ext]
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // Should be (..., '[path]')
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using glob:

```js
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  context: __dirname,
  entry: glob.sync('./js/**/*.js').reduce((acc, path) => {
    acc[path] = path;
    return acc;
  }, {}),
  output: {
    filename: '[name]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```